Hide a button based on several item values in APEX
I'm trying to hide a button based on a null value check of 5 page items.
I'm starting out by hiding the button on page load, and then using the DA to show it if all fields are not null.
My button static id is create_btn in a region called buttons
Here is my JavaScript expression.
function checkFields() {
  const field1 = apex.item("P4_NAME_MAIL").getValue();
  const field2 = apex.item("P4_ADDRESS_MAIL").getValue();
  const field3 = apex.item("P4_CITY_MAIL").getValue();
  const field4 = apex.item("P4_STATE_MAIL").getValue();
  const field5 = apex.item("P4_ZIP_MAIL").getValue();

  const buttonItem = apex.region("buttons").getItem("create_btn");

  if (field1 && field2 && field3 && field4 && field5) {
    // All fields are not null, show the button
    if (buttonItem) {
      buttonItem.show();
      buttonItem.setLabel("Submit");
    }
  } else {
    // One or more fields are null, hide the button
    if (buttonItem) {
      buttonItem.hide();
    }
  }
}

But when I test this the button is never showed?
Thanks for any help.
Oracle APEX 24.1.1

This can be done in a DA without any javascript coding. In my example there are only 2 items but you get the point
Dynamic Action:

Add a true action of "Hide" > "Button" and a false action of "Show" > "Button"
Instead of a "Change" event you could also look at "Lose Focus".
I would not use "fire on initialization" attribute of the actions to show or hide the button on page load. Instead add an style directive on the button to hide by default and then let the DA show it if needed. This prevents the flickering on load.

